# Chef - how to install postgresql using LWRP and recipes

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install postgresql using opscode LWRP. I get an error

```
You must set node['postgresql']['password']['postgres'] in chef-solo mode
```

Here is my recipe

```
include_recipe 'postgresql::server'
```

All documentation I have seen describes using nodes but I want to put the equivalent of the json code below into a recipe using attributes. Is there any way to do it?

```
"postgresql" : {
  "config": {
      "ssl": "false",
      "listen_addresses": "*"
    },      
  "password" : {
    "postgres" : "1234"
  },
  "pg_hba": [
     { "type": "host",  "db": "all", "user": "postgres", "addr": "119.9.40.50/32", "method": "md5" }
  ]
},
```

The full error is here

```
28:    missing_attrs = %w{       
29:      postgres       
30:    }.select do |attr|       
31:      node['postgresql']['password'][attr].nil?       
32:    end.map { |attr| "node['postgresql']['password']['#{attr}']" }       
33:         
34:    if !missing_attrs.empty?       
35>>     Chef::Application.fatal!([       
36:          "You must set #{missing_attrs.join(', ')} in chef-solo mode.",       
37:          "For more information, see https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/postgresql#chef-solo-note"       
38:        ].join(' '))       
39:    end       
40:  else       
41:    # TODO: The "secure_password" is randomly generated plain text, so it       
42:    # should be converted to a PostgreSQL specific "encrypted password" if       
43:    # it should actually install a password (as opposed to disable password       
44:    # login for user 'postgres'). However, a random password wouldn't be
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to `attributes/default.rb` in your cookbook:

```
default['postgresql']['password']['postgres'] = "xxx"
```

This does not add it "into a recipe using attributes", but it adds it to a cookbook. You can set attributes in recipes directly, too, but I see no reason to do this now (you can do it there with `node.default[...]`).

(you can choose any file name ending with `.rb`, it doesn't have to be `default.rb`, but I would say it's kinda convention)

Comment: Same error. I had already tried that. I want to use only a recipe and stay away from nodes and roles.

Comment: You can't avoid nodes. The node is the thing that runs chef. What I meant with "your cookbook": Did you add an additional cookbook to the node's run list in which you place the line I mentioned above? Is your code on github? Would make things easier.

Comment: I've scratched a tiny wrapper cookbook for you: https://gist.github.com/StephenKing/8939285
Just create the files mentined in the gist as a new cookbook `my_postgresql` and add `recipe[my_postgresql]` to the node's run list instead of `recipe[postgresql::server]`. I hope this helps.

Comment: To finally answer your real question (how to transform the JSON data to ruby) instead of talking about the symptom of an undefined password - just follow my example and use `default['postgresql']['config']['ssl'] = false` etc.

Comment: default['postgresql']['pg_hba']['type'] = "host" gives me an error "van't convert string into Integer".

Comment: I suggest that you put your code online as e.g. a git repo. otherwise I feel like I cannot help.

Comment: okay.. indeed, I'm wondering why a `default` attribute isn't sufficient. Using an override attribute or specifying it in the `Vagrantfile` helps. See my [PR](https://github.com/markhorrocks/my-postgresql/pull/1).

Comment: I don't see the rationale behind putting this in the Vagrant file since I need ultimately to cook a real sever. I put node.override in attributes/default.rb and I get the following error. How can I attach the attributes to the recipe rather than the cookbook?  Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
       ---- End output of apt-get -q -y install postgresql-client-9.1=9.1.10-0ubuntu12.04 ----

Comment: Different problem now. Include the `apt` cookbook to do an `apt-get update`.
If you use chef-solo on a real server, then just put the password hash (a hash!) into the cookbook, or read it from an encrypted data bag.

Comment: I still get Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (can't convert Symbol into Integer) on line #20:       
       
 18: <% node['postgresql']['pg_hba'].each do |auth| -%>

Comment: But that file is overwritten every time I run `vagrant provision`?

Comment: Which file do you mean?